# Having trouble understanding Diestel's exercise 14 from Chapter 1

Tags: graph-theory

The exercise is the following: Is there a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, every graph of minimum degree at least $f(k)$ is $k$-connected?

I am not sure why but I have really hard time connecting the mapping f to any graph G. I mean that if I have understood what is being asked, we want to find out whether or not is it possible parametrize the minimum degree of a $k$-connected graph. If this is the case, how are you supposed to approach a problem like this? What should be your first thought when you are asked: "Does there exists a mapping so that graphs having a property defined by this mapping have or do not have some other property"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you can always take two disjoint copies of $K_{f(k)+1}$, which will have minimum degree $f(k)$ but not be $k$-connected or even connected.

---

To read the question, you should think "okay, we're looking at the family of all graphs that are not $k$-connected. Can I make their minimum degree arbitrarily high? Or does some obstacle stop me?"

The actual function $f(k)$ should not be your first priority. If you were able to prove some upper bound on the maximum degree, you could turn that into an $f(k)$ later - note that the problem doesn't even ask you for the *best possible* $f(k)$.

Comment: I see. To make this a bit more interesting, if we were tasked with almost the same problem, but restricted to family of graphs that are  $(k - c)$-connected for $c < k$, are we in a better position to find our $f$? Now we know that the graphs have at least some connectivity, or is the extra information just there to trick us, because we can raise the minimum connectivity arbitrarily high?

Comment: The extra information doesn't help. Instead of making the copies of $K_{f(k)+1}$ disjoint, you can make them share $k-c$ vertices.

Comment: So just to make sure that I understood what you said: We cannot have such function because we can take an arbitrary complete graph that has a minimum degree of $f(k)$, by setting the graph to be $K_{f(k)+1}$. But that graph is $(k-1)$-connected and the issue remains true for any $f(k)$.

And for the general case, we can have a graph whose two components share $k - c$ vertices, making that graph $(k - c)$-connected, but as those two components are complete graph, every vertex has high enough degree?

Comment: That's exactly it.